# changing the name of a function in a loop

Tags: python, function, loops

I didn't find the answer my problem

I have function with names stage_1(), stage_2() e.t.c (to 8).

Can I run it using loop?

```
stage = 1 
for i in range(8):
      print((f'stage_{stage}'))
      stage +=1
```

I know this is wrong. what is the right way?

Comment: Looks like you could benefit from a dictionary.

Comment: The right way would be hard to say without more detail about the stages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I have function with names stage_1(), stage_2() e.t.c (to 8).*

Actually this is a very **bad** idea.

---

> *Can I run it using loop?*

For sure! You can do it using [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals):

```
for i in range(1, 8):
    current_function = globals()[f"stage_{i}"]
    result_of_current_function = current_function()
```

Or even using [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) or [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

```
for i in range(1, 8): # Range should start from 1
    eval(f"stage_{i}()") # or exec
```

---

Do you remember when I told you *"This is a very **bad** idea"*?

A better idea would be to store the functions into a `list`:

```
functions_list = [
    stage_1, stage_2, stage_3,
    stage_4, stage_5, stage_6,
    stage_7
]
```

In the end you could call them in a `for` loop this way:

```
for function in functions_list:
    function()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run function in loop like this, you should use `eval()`

```
stage = 1 
for i in range(8):
      print(eval((f'stage_{stage}')))
      stage +=1
```

but using `eval()` is wrong habbit, that is very unsecure, [explanation](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)